# Бан всех участников дискорд сервера одной командой на python боте

Tags: python, discord, бот

Можно ли каким-нибудь образом забанить всех участников одной командой? Если способ имеется, хотелось бы узнать полную команду, с самим ботом.

Comment: Попробуй поискать в документации. Там что-то да найдется. Ссылка на документацию: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html

Answer (score 0):

Нужно перебрать всех участников на сервере и каждого забанить, как это сделать узнаешь в документации.